# When i change the router, how can i reset the vuex state or data as default?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

i dont’ fully understand this router and vuex state… help me!

actufally if i dont use SPA if i move the menu, it will automatically reload.

but in SPA, every thing stays put.

event though i move to another cmp, it stays.

how can i do this?

1) is there any way to reload the page? like refresh

2) or how can i set default vuex state when i change the router?

[image]
thanks guys!

Comment: The whole purpose of state is to persist data across your app. If you don't want it persisted and you want some default data set when you init some component, simply provide it in `data` of that component. If you want that data to set the current state's value, do so in `mounted()` of the component that should "default" the state. So that everytime you navigate back to the route rendering your component, the state gets reset. You could reset it on route change, but you'll quickly find you want some route changes to reset and some others not to, so it's easier in mounted of selected components.

Answer (score -1):

To change your data in store you will need:

1. a getter (method) in store
2. a mutation so you can change your state of store

and when your routes changes :-

```
this.$store.dispatch("storeName/getterName", dataYouWantToSend);
```

inside store under getters object you can write :-

```
 getterName({ commit }, dataSentWhenRouterChanges) {
   commit("MUTATION_NAME", dataSentWhenRouterChanges);
 }
```

and after that change state in mutation under mutations like:-

```
MUTATION_NAME(state, dataSentWhenRouterChanges) {
  state.yourStateYouWantToChange = dataSentWhenRouterChanges;
},
```